# Simple Excel Macro for cell validation for numbers only

Tags: validation, vba, excel

I'm new to creating macros in Excel. Can anyone help me with a simple example? I want to force a cell to only take numeric, but not alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 5):

If a non-macro solution is okay, you can use Excel's Data Validation feature to do this really easily.  Just select the cell(s) to which you want to apply the data validation rule.  Click 'Data Validation' on the Data ribbon.  Choose to allow 'Custom' values, and enter the formula `=ISNUMBER(A1)`, where `A1` is the cell or top-left cell of the range to which you are applying the validation rule.

[image]